# How to convert a multipolygon to multilines with Python?

Tags: python, shapefile

How can I convert MultiPolygon to Multiline?

I want to work with the boundary of multipolygon. In R I can just do :

`as(my_multi_polygone, 'SpatialLines')`

But I don't know how to do it in Python?

Comment: Look at the Shapely library and here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277262/93097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `multip` is the collection of polygons representing the MultiPolygon collection.

```
multiLines = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString([x.exterior for x in multip])
```

Comment: Thanks @saph_top it work but i make for iteration on the geometry of multipoly. `multiLines = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString([x.exterior for x in multip.geometry])`